# Can you choose the variables of a state function?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I'm confused. I was first introduced to entropy as a state function of internal energy and volume

$$S(U,V) \Rightarrow dS = C_v\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{T} - p\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{T}  $$

wich is the thermodynamic identity, but now I see that it can also be written as

$$S(T,p) \Rightarrow dS = C_p\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{T} + k\mathrm{d}p $$

I don't understand, if I can choose the parameters I could just decide that entropy is a function of the number of molecules of my gas so there would be no variation in entropy as long as it's in a closed container...

Can someone explain to me the logic behind this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I am working in unit-mass bases (with lower-case symbols).

- Since,

[image]

- We have,

[image]

- So that,

[image]

---

**Notes:**

1. The internal energy is a function of the constant volume specific heat, and the latter is a function of temperature.
2. The enthalpy is a function of the constant pressure specific heat, and the latter is a function of temperature.
3. Remember the state postulate: the state of a simple compressible system is completely specified by two independent, intensive properties (intensive: independent of mass. e.g., P, T, or v "or p the density, the reciprocal or v"). This is true as long as there is no electrical, magnetic, gravitational, motion or surface tension effects.
4. Notice the left-hand side (ds) and the right-hand ones (du, dh, dT, dv, dP), and think about integration. What would be the variable of integration in each of these equations? That is where the dependency (functionality) came from.